# Powershell: Multipart RAR extraction

Tags: powershell, extract, rar, winrar

I have a folder with n number of rar files with some having .part01,.part02 as they are divided. the code i am currently using is given below.

```
$Rars = Get-ChildItem -path 'c:\demopath' -filter "*.rar"  
$Destination = 'c:\demopath'
$WinRar = "C:\Program Files\WinRAR\WinRAR.exe"


foreach ($rar in $Rars)
{
&$Winrar x -y $rar.FullName $Destination
Get-Process winrar | Wait-Process
}
```

This code is running many times to extract same file again and again by the number of parts it has. example if the file is having 3 parts it will get extract same file 3 times (overwriting the previously extracted file). for single rar file there is no issue. if i only give "x" then it is giving popups for file already exists. need a solution which will not give any popups and extract only if same name file is not there in the directory.
can someone help me to fix this issue?

Comment: `UnRAR.exe`, `Rar.exe` and `WinRAR.exe` support all `C:\demopath\*.rar` as archive file name pattern for extracting all archives in specified directory to either specified destination directory or subdirectories in specified destination directory with each subdirectory name being the name of an archive file on using switch `-ad`. All three executables auto-detect multi-volume archives in source directory and extract them all only once. So you would not have needed a PowerShell script at all with a loop to extract all *.rar archive files in a directory.

Comment: The text file `Rar.txt` in program files folder of __WinRAR__ being manual for console version `Rar.exe` (and `UnRAR.exe`) explains this possibility of extraction of multiple archives with one command line. And help of __WinRAR__ on __Contents__ tab under list item __Command line mode__ explains this method also for GUI version  `WinRAR.exe`. So reading the documentation would have been useful in your case.

Comment: i need to use powershell to automate few other tasks. so please give your solution keeping powershell in mind.

Answer (score 1):

solved the issue with using unrar freeware in winrar directory.
all i needed was to use the "-o-" parameter to stop overwriting the existing extracted file. same command will work with winrar.exe as well

```
&$UnRAR x -o- $rar.FullName $Destination
```